# SQL -- Dividing two results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two querys below, both of which are feeding from the same "player" table. I want to divide query 1 by query 2 to get a relevant percentage. Im relatively new to more detailed SQL queries, as well as posting on forums...but please let me know if you have any suggestions on how to combine this to get the relevant percentage result.

#### 1

```
Select
  sysdate,sum(Count(init_dtime))
From Player p
Where
  Trunc(Init_Dtime) > Trunc(Sysdate) - 7 
  And Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
  and trunc(create_dtime) < to_date('2015-sep-9','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By Trunc(Init_Dtime)
Order By Trunc(Init_Dtime) Asc
```

#### 2

```
Select
  Sum(Count(Create_Dtime))
From Player P
where 
  Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
  And Trunc(Create_Dtime) < To_Date('2015-sep-9','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group By Trunc(create_Dtime)
Order By Trunc(create_Dtime) Asc
```

Comment: You already have two answers, which surprises me, because I don't understand the question. Do you want one number or a number per player? If the answers are not what you want, then please try by posting an original data set from the player table, an expected result set and an explanation of the transformation.

Comment: @Rob van Wijk - sorry for the lack of clarity. I am trying to get one total number for all of the players combined. there are a lot of columns in the "player" table, but the ones that are important here are: 1)"create_dtime" which is the date that specific player made an account and 2) init d_time which is the latest date that a specific player has logged on. For all of the players within a certain date range, i want to divide query 1 (all active players within the last 7 days, for users that created an account after 3/1/12) by query 2 (total users who created an account after 3/1/12)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just say

```
select sysdate,
       count((init_dtime)) / sum((Create_Dtime)) * 100 as percentage
  from Player p
 where Trunc(Init_Dtime) > Trunc(Sysdate) - 7 
   and Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
   and trunc(create_dtime) < to_date('2015-sep-9','yyyy-mon-dd')
   order by percentage asc
```

The `group by` in the SQLs are not needed as you are not really grouping by something. `group by` is useful when you need the percentage by player, for instance. Then you would say `group by player_id` and in the `select` would have the `player_id`:

```
select player_id, count(…)
  from …
 where …
group by player_id
```

EDIT:
If the where clauses are different:

```
select sysdate, 
       (
           (select count((init_dtime))
             from player p
            where trunc(Init_Dtime) > trunc(Sysdate) - 7 
              and Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
              and trunc(create_dtime) < to_date('2015-sep-9','yyyy-mon-dd'))
            / 
           (select count((Create_Dtime))
              from player P
             where trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-mar-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
               and trunc(Create_Dtime) < To_Date('2015-sep-9','yyyy-mon-dd'))
       ) * 100 as percentage
from dual
```

Comment: They have different `WHERE` clauses though

Comment: Mike - exactly.. although eveything is feeding from the player table, the two querys are structured upon different where criteria..i can manually just take the 2 queries and divide them on my own, but where's the fun in that!? I figured I'd start using this forum to try and expand my automation.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Did not notice that. Will update the answer.

Comment: Nivas- appreciate your quick responses. but it says SQL command not properly ended. I tried adding a parenthesis at the end, but im getting the same area. Could there be anything missing? Could it be grouping, because when I try to run the numerator by itself, it says it needs a group by function included. Once again, appreciate the help!

Comment: @Stuav I just saw something: what are you trying to do when you say `sum(Count(init_dtime))`?

Comment: @Nivas, init_dtime is a date section, which represent the latest logon date by a user. Im trying to get a count of those logon dates which fall within the last 7 days, but only for users that created an account after Mar 1-2012. Let me know if that helps, other wise I can do as rob suggested and post some greater detail. Thanks!

Comment: @Stuav Then what you need is `select count()…` I updated my answer.

Comment: @Nivas, the numerator and denominator do work separately now...but when i run the whole query i still get the "SQL command not properly ended" notice...does that notice mean anything specifically?

Comment: Can you try `(select 1) / (select 2) * 100` in the same line? Also, does `select 1` and `select 2` give single numeric answers?

Comment: It could very well be the parentheses. A similar sql works here. You can use this as your base: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a6f5/10

Comment: It worked! It was just a matter of bringing select 1/select two in the same line. Thanks so much for your help on this!